# Modern Objective-C and @synthesize

Tags: objective-c, synthesize

I'm trying convert my code to Modern Objective-C style. How i read here http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Basics_of_Modern_Objective-C": "In the case of Modern Objective-C, however, the synthesis takes place by default, making the use of @synthesize declarations unnecessary. When using default property synthesize, instance variable properties are accessible from within code using the property name prefixed with an underscore."

However, I have:

Relationship.h

```
@interface Relationship : NSObject <NSCoding>
//...
@property(nonatomic, weak) Person* first;
//...
@end`
```

OtherRelationship.h

```
#import "Relationship.h"

@interface OtherRelationship : Relationship

@end
```

OtherRelationship.m

```
#import "OtherRelationship.h"

@implementation OtherRelationship

@synthesize first = _first;

- (void)foo
{
NSLog(@"%@", _first);
}
```

and it's working. But when i delete

```
 @synthesize first = _first;
```

i get "Use of undeclared identifier '_first'" error. Does inheritanced variables doesn't work with autosynthesize or should i looking for problem elsewhere?

Comment: There's no declaration of `first` property in your example.   Is it missing from your .h or just from the snippet you sent?

Comment: I don't see anything named "first" in Relationship.h

Comment: Note that you can drop the `@synthesize` entirely.

Comment: I've got first in my code, i corrected this above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backing ivar in the superclass is @private to the subclass. That is, the subclass may call self.first, but not _first. If you want to @synthesize again, use a different name because you can't refer to _first. For example, replace with `@synthesize first = _ffirst;` or just drop the @synthesize.

Comment: So I can drop @synthesize, but then I must make "NSLog(@"%@", self.first)"?

Comment: Ok, that's look good. But why i can't add `@property(nonatomic, weak) Person* first;` to OtherRelationship interface (this IMO should make first @public for OtherRelationship class) and then just drop @synthesize and use _first in OtherRelationship implementation?

Comment: If a subclass synthesizes a property already synthesized in a superclass, the new accessors override the old ones. So you are still interfering with the first variable defined in the superclass.